# Confused regarding android project

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I am a software developer with 1.2 years of experience in front end development (Microsoft technology stack). My motto is to do code but as I had done a course in web designing & development so my company had assigned me role of web designer as well. In the starting I was doing design and code both but later on company had included few more developers and role of designing (website & graphics) has been doing full time by me, solely.

Since 8 months I am doing this designing work. However, they are asking me to work on an android mobile app project now-a-days.

for this project, I don't find myself mentally prepare. Because, I have already meandered on my .net developer career line & this project will surely made me out of the scope of .net career. (I am trying to make switch too now)

Although, I am trying my best to not do this project but some of my well-wishers are saying that you should do this android project.

I would like to ask to you, whether should I work on this assignment or should switch the  company.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site Nikhil. Unfortunately we can't really tell you what to do in your situation as [personal advice isn't a good fit for our Q&A format](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/#2695). It's not practical for us to answer a question that depends so heavily on your own abilities, preferences or circumstances. We *can* answer specific questions on how to handle a workplace situation, accomplish a goal or come to a decision on a particular problem. If you can reword your question to fit those criteria please do so, otherwise your post will likely be closed.

Comment: Lilienthal : thank you so much for making me aware about the reason of down-vote. Please excuse-me for the negligence of the guidelines.
however I would like to state here that very kind answer of this question has open an opportunity to understand the Goal of my software development career. I was totally unaware about the things that mr. @Kevin has wrote here. I would hope every software developer should be teach these things even before s/he take his/her first lecture for software engineering course. I would like you to close this question now. Thank you again!

Comment: You are quite welcome though I'd like to point out that I didn't downvote your question. In future or if you have further questions about this topic I'd urge you to ask for some input on the [Workplace chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) where we aren't so strict about the site guidelines and where we may be able to give you more personalised advice or point you to useful links or resources. Users there can also help you (re)write a question so that it's on-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the assignment. You are getting paid to get experience on a hot new stack. And your .NET experience won't become stale in three months. If you want to specialize, specialize in an application area, not a technology. Technologies like .NET come and go. Others will disagree but to me .NET looks like a fading star. The big web companies are almost all running on Linux servers, the mobile space is growing fast and it's almost entirely Android or IoS.

Comment: I totally disagree with you about .NET, but I totally agree with the rest of your answer. You don't want to be pigeon-holed on _any_ one technology, so chances to learn new tech on your employer's dime are like gold. Grab them with both hands!!

Comment: What do you think stackexchange runs on?

Comment: kevin, @Carson63000 : Thanks so much for the answer. However, I could not get it this specialization regarding application. I meant what do you want to say with this? Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffO: I know stackexchange runs on .NET. Of course so do the MSN sites. Outside Microsoft, Stack Exchange may be the largest and most interesting.NET site. AFAIK all the ultra-high-traffic sites (Amazon, Google, Facebook, Netflix, Twitter, Yahoo, etc.) are running on Linux.

Comment: @Nikhil: Applications areas are independent of languages and stacks, like user experience, graphics, optimization, geographical information, big data, etc. Those skills are always valuable. Languages and come and go.